# Using a pointer to const char as a second argument for va_start

Tags: c, unix, pointers

I am working on *Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment 3-Edition* , and I find this code

```
err_msg(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list     ap;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    err_doit(0, 0, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

and `err_doit` is :

```
static void
err_doit(int errnoflag, int error, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    char    buf[MAXLINE];

    vsnprintf(buf, MAXLINE-1, fmt, ap);
    if (errnoflag)
        snprintf(buf+strlen(buf), MAXLINE-strlen(buf)-1, ": %s",
          strerror(error));
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    fflush(stdout);     /* in case stdout and stderr are the same */
    fputs(buf, stderr);
    fflush(NULL);       /* flushes all stdio output streams */
}
```

What I didn't understand, is why the author passed a pointer to `const char` as an argument for `va_start`. As far as I know, you only allowed to pass the number of arguments represented by the ellipses section, as stated here:

```
void f1(int n, ...);
int f2(const char * s, int k, ...);
```

The rightmost parameter (the one just before the ellipses) plays a special role; the standard uses
the term `parmN` as a name to use in discussion. In the preceding examples, parmN would be `n`
for the first case and `k` for the second case. **The actual argument passed to this parameter will
be the number of arguments represented by the ellipses section**. *source:
C Primer Plus by Stephen Prata.*

Also I checked the two examples written in *ISO C Standard:  7.15  Variable arguments*  and I found out that they pass too an *`int`* variable to `va_start` macro.

I am afraid that It's me who missed a point somewhere. I hope someone informs me.

Answer (score 5):

The second argument to `va_start` is the last "real" argument, before the var-args arguments begin.

The `err_msg()`  function only has a single normal argument, the `const char *fmt` pointer, so then clearly that is the last argument before the var-args part and should be passed to `va_start()`.

[The manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start) says:

> The argument last is the name of the last argument before the variable argument list, that is, the last argument of which the calling function knows the type.

The actual type of the second argument to `va_list` doesn't matter.

Also note that the quite common [`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) function very probably does exactly this, as it too only has a single "ordinary" argument, the format string.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h):

> The macro `va_start` is then called with two arguments: the first is the variable declared of the type `va_list`, the second is the name of the last named parameter of the function.

Or from the [C standard library](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_va_start.htm):

> The C library macro `void va_start(va_list ap, last_arg)` initializes `ap` variable to be used with the `va_arg` and `va_end` macros. The `last_arg` is the last known fixed argument being passed to the function ie. the argument before the ellipsis.

The point is that you need a *standard* argument before the `...` to be able to give it to `va_start`. `va_start` will use it only to retrieve the supplementary arguments (pure C cooking).

What the last *standard* argument is is not relevant, but you **may** want to use it to know the number of supplementary arguments. Also this is an example of usage and I think that is what your source does: an example of usage.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've quoted the book correctly, that statement:

> The actual argument passed to this parameter will be the number of arguments represented by the ellipses section.

is incorrect, or at least misleading.

In your specific examples:

```
void f1(int n, ...);
int f2(const char * s, int k, ...);
```

the last named parameter before the ellipsis happens to be an `int` whose value presumably is intended to specify the number of arguments corresponding to the `...`.

That's a reasonable convention (though you still need to specify the *types* of those arguments), but it's not required by the language.

The second argument to `va_start()` is always the *name* (not the value) of the last named parameter. Since `va_start` is a macro, not a function, the usual rule that all arguments are passed by value does not apply. Internally, `va_start` uses the parameter name to determine where in memory (or in registers) it can find the additional argument values. (There is no portable way to do this, so the actual definition of `va_start` is not specified by the standard; it has to be customized for each compiler.)

All that's really required is that the function must be able to figure out *somehow* the number and types of the arguments passed by the caller. `printf` does this by parsing the format string. `execl()` (a POSIX function, not defined by ISO C) does it by assuming that all the arguments are of type `char*`, and collecting arguments until it finds a null pointer. Other mechanisms are possible. And if the caller passes inconsistent arguments, the behavior is undefined; there's no way for the caller to detect an error.

Even in your example, the second argument to `va_start` is *not* "the number of arguments represented by the ellipses section". It's the name of a parameter. Even if the parameter value happens to be, say, `3`, passing a literal `3` to `va_start` would be incorrect. The function will determine the number of arguments simply by reading the value of the named parameter, not by anything related to `va_start`.

The semantics of the `va_start` macro, and other items defined in `<stdarg.h>` are described in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.16.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard only requires the last argument before the ellipsis to be default-promoted and not be declared with function or array type (though function pointer and pointer type are allowed, so this is merely a syntactical restriction).

For `f1` and `f2`, the last named argument holds the number of arguments passed, though this is entirely conventional.

Examples from the standard library where this is handled differently are `printf` (the number (and types) of the arguments is determined by the format string) and `execl` (the end of the argument list is marked by a `NULL` pointer).

Comment: Can you clarify your comment about '[t]he last named argument often holds the number of arguments passed'?  I'm wondering if you can cite an example where it is used like that.  In my experience, most functions do not use it for that (think `printf()` and `scanf()` and friends) — though I did write a function with a count in that position instead of using a null pointer to mark the end of the arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Even if I could give an example from a popular library where it is an argument count, this hardly would justify "often". The only place where I've regularly seen this, is in tutorials (and questions like this one). Thinking about it, it usually isn't nicer to use than null-termination or an array and a size argument, as the arguments must be counted manually (or by some macro hackery). Thanks for correction!